# Ordenação de dados: Bubble sort ou metodo sort das Collections

Tags: java, classificação

Qual é mais eficiente para ordenar uma grande quantidade de dados passada por um vetor:

- *Bubble sort*
- Usar os próprios recursos das *Collections*, por exemplo o método *Sort*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O método sort do Java utiliza o *merge sort* que é garantido atuar com uma complexidade eficiente (n log n) com qualquer tipo de dados. O que é bem melhor que o bubble sort que é n2.

Entre as duas opções, fique com os recursos das *Collections*.

Agora, há a possibilidade de se você entender os algoritmos de ordenação, conseguir otimizar e melhorar a performance. Recomendo esse estudo se achar que não está te atendendo tão bem assim o algoritmo ainda.

Comment: Estou estudando para entender como as duas funcionam, hoje com o avanço do hardware, e pela praticidade que a collection nos da, é melhor ultiliza-la, poderia bota na minha pergunta..